# Importance of the Rayleigh Quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm self studying linear algebra, and I'm confused about the importance of the Rayleigh Quotient.  For the case where $M=I$, it seems to be a way to express the eigenvalues of a matrix $H$ in terms of critical points.  However, when $M$ is just a positive self-adjoint mapping, what does it actually mean to minimise the general Rayleigh quotient?
$$R_{H,M}=\frac{(x,Hx)}{(x,Mx)}$$

Also, it seems to me that the process of minimising it by perturbation always occurs near the eigenvectors of $H$.  Are there any cases where we do not start with the eigenvectors of $H$, or are all results found in terms of the eigenvectors of $H$, e.g. the vector minimising $R_{H,M}$ is given by the relation
$$Hf=bMf$$
where $f$ is an eigenvector of $H$, and $b$ is the minimum value of $R_{H,M}$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem